# What is the structural factor in context of wind loads?

Tags: structural-engineering

Coefficient called "structural factor" appears in building codes when calculation of wind loads in discussed. The wind load is proportional to this factor.

I have a lot of trouble understanding its meaning. One definition from [here](https://www.lisa.blue/help/wind_structural_factor_cscd/en_GB) says:

> The structural factor takes into account the absence of pressures simultaneity to the surface of the construction and of vibration of the structure caused by the turbulence.

Eurocodes, for example gave no clearer explanation. Could somebody explain the meaning in more detail? **What is meant by "absence of pressure simultaneity", and how does a multiplicative factor account for this?**

Comment: that there is a pressure difference between the two surfaces, often caused by shape.

Answer (score 1):

For a large structure, the wind load will not reach its peak value on all surfaces at the exact same time, but at slightly different points in time. Therefore, the ability of the maximum total wind load to excite dynamic vibrations in the structure may be reduced compared to the simplification of multiplying peak pressure with total area and applying that as the maximum value of the dynamic, varying load.

For more information, see EN1991-1-4 section 6.3.1 and annex B.